# How to speed this kind of for-loop?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, max, vectorization

I would like to compute the maximum of translated images along the direction of a given axis. I know about [`ordfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/ordfilt2.html), however I would like to avoid using the Image Processing Toolbox.

So here is the code I have so far:

```
imInput = imread('tire.tif');
n = 10;

imMax = imInput(:, n:end);
for i = 1:(n-1)
    imMax = max(imMax, imInput(:, i:end-(n-i)));
end
```

Is it possible to avoid using a for-loop in order to speed the computation up, and, if so, how?

---

**First edit**: Using Octave's code for `im2col` is actually 50% slower.

**Second edit**: Pre-allocating did not appear to improve the result enough.

```
sz = [size(imInput,1), size(imInput,2)-n+1];

range_j = 1:size(imInput, 2)-sz(2)+1;
range_i = 1:size(imInput, 1)-sz(1)+1;

B = zeros(prod(sz), length(range_j)*length(range_i));

counter = 0;
for j = range_j % left to right
    for i = range_i % up to bottom
        counter = counter + 1;
        v = imInput(i:i+sz(1)-1, j:j+sz(2)-1);
        B(:, counter) = v(:);            
    end
end

imMax = reshape(max(B, [], 2), sz);
```

**Third edit**: I shall show the timings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the answer to this question about doing a rolling median in c.  I've successfully made it into a mex function and it is way faster than even ordfilt2.  It will take some work to do a max, but I'm sure it's possible.

[Rolling median in C - Turlach implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527437/rolling-median-in-c-turlach-implementation)

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here's a vectorized solution using [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html) function from the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
imInput = imread('tire.tif');
n = 10;

sz = [size(imInput,1) size(imInput,2)-n+1];
imMax = reshape(max(im2col(imInput, sz, 'sliding'),[],2), sz);
imshow(imMax)
```

[image: screenshot]

You could perhaps write your own version of IM2COL as it simply consists of well crafted indexing, or even look at how [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/im2col.html) [implements](http://octave.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/octave/trunk/octave-forge/main/image/inst/im2col.m?revision=8350&view=markup) it.

Comment: Thanks, but it is actually 50% slower. :'(

Comment: @wok: I wasn't implying that its the best implementation possible... Looking at the code you posted, the matrix `B` is dynamically increasing in size, it obviously would get much faster if you preallocate.

Comment: Without seeing the timing results (I doubt the difference to be that significant), I suggest you then stick with your original for-loop. After all, it does have the advantage of minimal space requirement...

Comment: Pre-allocation does improve the result, but not that much. I guess a mex-file will be the way to go then. Anyway, thanks for `im2col`, it should be useful.