# Using scipy.weave.inline for fast 2D median filtering

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, filtering, median

I have a bottleneck in a 2D median filter (3x3 window) I use on a very large set of images, and I'd like to try and optimize it.  I've tested `scipy.ndimage` median_filter, as well as `PIL`, `scipy.signal` and `scikits-image`. However, browsing in SO I've learned that there's a fast O(n) median filter out there in C (Median Filtering in Constant Time see [Rolling median algorithm in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309263/rolling-median-algorithm-in-c)), and I wondered whether I can implement it in Python using scipy.weave.inline ?
Any suggestions on an alternative route?

Comment: I have a cython wrapper for Perreault + Hebert, Median Filtering in Constant Time, someplace -- but that'd be overkill for 3x3, better do a sorting network, 9 inputs in 25 compares. Are the inputs 0..255 or what ?

Comment: Do you just want to process your image set? Is [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) an alternative route? [medianBlure](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#medianblur) perhaps? You also have CUDA and OpenCl implementations.

Comment: most of the code framework is already in python, small parts are in matlab, it would be best to implement this part of the code in python somehow.

Comment: @natan OpenCV has a nice Python interface for most of its functionality. E.g. from the documentation:
 Python: cv2.medianBlur(src, ksize[, dst]) → dst

Comment: What "1" are you referring to in `O(1)`? I don't think you can expect to be less than linear in the the amount of pixels in your image.

Comment: @eickenberg, I guess you are right and it means linear, so O(n) is the right way to write it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
[Rolling median in C - Turlach implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527437/rolling-median-in-c-turlach-implementation)

http://ideone.com/8VVEa

Usage:

```
Mediator* m = MediatorNew(9);
for (...)
{
      MediatorInsert(m, value);
      median = MediatorMedian(m);
}
```

I believe this is the same as the R algo, but cleaner (amazingly so, in fact).

You can either wrap this, or port it and use Numba (or Cython).  I think I'd recommend Numba over Cython, if nothing else because it *is* plain old python code.

I suggest adding this to scikits, if it runs faster than the one in scikits already :)

Comment: thanks Alex, I haven't tried that yet, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

If your still interested I'd try numpy's reshape and median:

```
a= some big array
a.reshape(N,3,3) #N being specific to your array
[numpy.median(m) for m in a]
```

I don't know how this scales compared to your testet methods but if you want to optimize with C you could fasten the for loop in the list comprehension...

Comment: This is elegant, but unfortunately it calculates the median of every non-overlapping 3x3, not the median of every possible 3x3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the underlying algorithm, but scikits-image has a [rolling median filter](http://scikits-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filter.html#median-filter).

Otherwise, I'd recommend writing it in [Cython](http://cython.org/) (C/Python pidgin language).  Be sure to check out the [convolution example/tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) for working with numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Also, by writing 3x3 I meant that the median window size is 3x3, the actual image it is used in is megapixles big.

Comment: Well, it seems that scikits is even slower than PIL and scipy.ndimage. Unfortunately, the images I work on are 16bit so the 0..255 option is not relevant. Next Cython...