# Calculating Median with Priority Queue

Tags: java, collections

I am doing this homework for coursera related course and am new to Java and DS and Algo. I won't be pasting my whole code here. But below is the problem I am facing with the relevant piece of code.

So, to retrieve the medians I am using `PriorityQueue` and `Comparator` Interface. From the below function I am trying to make two `PriorityQueue`s such that for example for 21 elements the `hLow` priority queue has 11 smallest elements and the `hHigh` has the 10 highest elements.

```
public static void addToStream (int k) {
    hLow.add (k);
    if (hLow.size() > (hHigh.size() + 1)) {
        hHigh.add(hLow.poll());
    }
}
```

The comparator function I have written for `hLow` is

```
hLComp = new Comparator <Integer> () {
        public int compare (Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }   
    };
```

and for `hHigh` is

```
hHComp = new Comparator <Integer> () {
        public int compare (Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return -o1.compareTo(o2);
        }   
    };
```

The problem I face is that that the

```
hHigh.add(hLow.poll())
```

retrieves the wrong value. For example if the first value is 3000 then then that's the median but when the second value comes in which for example is 6000. Then the code enters in the if condition and after that the `hHigh.peek` shows 3000 and `hLow.peek` shows 6000.  Which is opposite to what I expect.

Comment: How are your queues sorted? Are they in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an entire class with an example of finding the median.

```
public class Median {

    static PriorityQueue<Integer> hHigh  = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(100, 
            new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare (Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });

    static PriorityQueue<Integer> hLow  = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(100, 
            new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare (Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return -o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });

    public static void addToStream (int k) {
        if (hHigh.size() == 0 || k > hHigh.peek()){
            hHigh.add(k);
        }

        else {
            hLow.add(k);
        }

        if (hLow.size() > (hHigh.size() + 1)) {
            hHigh.add(hLow.poll());
        }
        if (hHigh.size() > hLow.size()){
            hLow.add(hHigh.poll()); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addToStream(3104);
        addToStream(6185);
        addToStream(7818);
        addToStream(2106);
        addToStream(5480);
        System.out.println(hLow.peek());
    }
}
```

This program prints out : 5480

Comment: try with 10, 9, 8. It shows me 10 as a median. I am debugging

Comment: the problem is with how the first few numbers are streamed . After the first three numbers it the function behaves as it should...

Comment: If you'll copy paste the class i wrote, and enter to add to stream 10 , 9 , 8 , than make the call to hLow.peek() youll get 9.

Comment: it doesnt. I am doing it a bit differently but it shouldnt matter https://gist.github.com/3181771

Comment: I need to see how you construct you're queue.

Comment: And by the way are you required to implement the median search in this fashion or could you to this other wise?

Answer (score 1):

The above method is buggy. Just try 5 4 3 you'll see.
Base case is needed for this algorithm. It's well explained here:

[Find running median from a stream of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657503/find-running-median-from-a-stream-of-integers)

Answer (score 0):

The values inside each queue will be sorted out in the way you implemented the comparator.
The way you implemented you're add function you're simply placing one in hLow than one in hHigh.

If you want to hold the bigger half in one queue and the other in the second you need to compare the values at the head of each queue.
Than according to the result you might need to make a swap between the queues, just like with the numbers you entered.

Try this for the add function :

First you need to assign hLow comparator to hHigh and vice versa.
Then after adding values hLow.peek() gives you the median.

```
public static void addToStream (int k) {
    if (hHigh.size() == 0 || k > hHigh.peek()){
        hHigh.add(k);
    }

    else {
        hLow.add(k);
    }

    if (hLow.size() > (hHigh.size() + 1)) {
        hHigh.add(hLow.poll());
    }
    if (hHigh.size() > hLow.size(){
        hLow.add(hHigh.poll()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: ..ok. So, can you tell me what modification should i made to the code ??

Comment: Try what i wrote tell me if it helped, i didn't run this program if it fails tell me and ill run it to see where is the problem.

Comment: its thrwoing null pointer exception at line if (k > hHigh.peek()). The reason is that at the first call to addToStream method there is no hHigh.peek values. How to solve this. Thanks !

Comment: Try the new one. And a new one :) just now.

Comment: Incorrect answers. I have debugged it for the first five numbers like 3104
6185
7818
2106
5480
. It always returns 3104 as a median

Comment: What is in the head of the hHigh queue - the maximum or minimum value?

Comment: This is how it looks after the first few iterations hLow : 3104
hHigh : null
hLow : 3104
hHigh : 6185
hLow : 3104
hHigh : 6185
hLow : 3104
hHigh : 6185
hLow : 3104
hHigh : 6185
hLow : 3104
hHigh : 6185

Comment: hLow comparator returns :  -o1.compareTo(o2);
hHigh comparator returns :  o1.compareTo(o2);
Now after adding the numbers hLow.peek() = median.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14460/discussion-between-oopsi-and-livingthing)