# Optimal algorithm to return largest k elements from an array of infinite number of elements in running stream

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stream

I have a running stream of integers, how can I take largest k elements from this stream at any point of time.

Comment: See [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35993/keep-kties-largest-elements-in-a-stream) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657503/find-running-median-from-a-stream-of-integers)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to populate a [min-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) of size `k`.

First, populate the heap with the first `k` elements.

Next, for each element in the stream - check if it is larger than the heap's head, and if it is - pop the current head, and insert the new element instead.

At any point during the stream - the heap contains the largest `k` elements.

This algorithm is `O(nlogk)`, where `n` is the number of elements encountered so far in the stream.

---

Another solution, a bit more complex but theoretically better in terms of asymptotic complexity in some cases, is to hold an array of `2k` elements.

First, load the first 2k elements.

Run [Selection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), and find the highest `k` out of them. Discard the rest, at this point you have only `k` elements left in the array.

Now, fill the array again with the next `k` elements, and repeat.

At each point, the array contains the `k` largest elements, and up to `k` more elements that are not the largest. You can run Selection Algorithm for each query on this array.

Run time analysis:

Maintaining the array: Each selection algorithm is `O(2k) = O(k)`. This is done once every `k` elements, so `n/k` times if `n` indicates the number of elements seen so far, which gives us `O(n/k * 2k) = O(n)`.

In addition, each query is `O(k)`, if the number of queries is `Q`, this gives us `O(n + Q*k)` run-time.

In order to this solution to be more efficient, we need `Q*k < nlogk`

```
Q*k < nlogk
Q < n/k * logk
```

So, if number of queries is limited as suggested above, this solution could be more efficient in terms of asymptotic complexity.

---

In practice, getting top k is usually done by using the min-heap solution, at least where I've seen the need of it.

Comment: Am i right to think that although this might be the easiest solution, depending on languages the "optimal" solution may vary ? I don't have anything in mind, just thinking out loud.

Comment: @Bartdude See edit, added another solution that might prove even more efficeint in terms of asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @amit, you might want to edit your answer - "check if it is smaller than the heap's head" should really be "check if it is larger than the heap's head". Smaller ones should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for noticing @stojke

Comment: The second approach is pretty interesting. I'll have to update my blog entry, http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/, to include that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also called Heavy Hitters .
Count Sketch Data Structures are the solution for this .

Ref :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch

Answer (score -2):

```
import heapq
def klargestelements(arr1,k):
    q=heapq.nlargest(k,arr1)
    return q
k=3
arr1=[1,2,4,5,6,7]
m=klargestelements(arr1,k)
print(m)
```

nsmallest or nlargest methods takes in the argument k and the array in which the min/max elements are to be found

Comment: The question said "running stream", not a fixed array.