# Calculating running median from a stream of doubles with more than 10 billlions numbers

Tags: c#, statistics, streaming, median

My app is receiving stream of doubles with total count more than 10 billions. And i need to calculate some statistical parameters from these numbers. I found ways to calculate average and mode.
But I have problems with median.
There is max heap/min heap solution for this purpose (given in the first answer there [Running median](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657503/find-running-median-from-a-stream-of-integers)). But in this way I must store 5 billions doubles in each heap (or more). Arrays, lists or dictionaries can't do this. How can I do it? And what must I do in described solution if my next element will be the same as element of maxHeap?

Comment: AFAIK *running* median is called so because it's calculated for last N items.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Moving_median)

Comment: Assuming you mean that you want to calculate the median for the whole data set every time a new number is added to the data set: You need to have all the numbers to know where the new median would be, so this is always going to require `O(N)` space.

Comment: You can allow large arrays in the .NET with the help of `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` [tweak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element)

Comment: Also, you can improve your algorithm, if you can read your stream more than once. In this case you can use some bucketing approach - choose some reasonable `range` value and than on the first pass count amount of the numbers in the buckets `[x..x + range]`. After this you can determine the bucket where median lies and then on the second pass use naive solution to find kth order statistics in the bucket.

Comment: "And what must I do in described solution if my next element will be the same as element of maxHeap?"
There is no limitation that a min/max heap must only contain unique numbers as far as I know.

Comment: You could also consider if you need the exact median or if an approximation would be sufficient.