# Find Median of K last numbers from Data Stream

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Problem:** An odd number `K` is given. At the input, we gradually receive a sequence of `N` numbers. After reading each number (except the first `K-1`), print the median of the last `K` numbers.

I solved it using two heaps (MaxHeap and MinHeap, e.g. [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657503/find-running-median-from-a-stream-of-integers) ) and added function `remove_element(value)` to both heaps. `remove_element(value)` iterates over the heap, looking for the value to remove. Removes it and then rebalances the tree. So it works in `O(K+log K)`.

And I solved the problem like this: by iterating the stream date, I add a new element to the heaps and delete the old one, which is already outside the window (`K+1`th element). So it works in `O(N*(K + log K + log K)) = O(N*K)`.

I'm wondering 1) if I correctly estimated the time complexity of the algorithm, 2) is it possible to speed up this algorithm. 3) if not (the algorithm is optimal), then how can I prove its optimality.

As for the third question, if my estimate of the O(N*K) algorithm is correct, I think it can be proven based on the obvious idea that in order to write out the median, we need to check all K elements for each of N requests

Comment: 1. yes 2. there are better ways to delete from a heap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better approach, make the heaps be heaps of `(value, i)`.  And now you don't need to remove stale values promptly, you can simply keep track of how many non-stale values are on each side, and throw away stale values when they pop up from the heap.

And if more than half of a heap is stale, then do garbage collection to remove stale values.

If you do this well, you should be able to solve this problem with `O(k)` extra memory in time `O(n log(k))`.